# Zend_Form_Element_Captcha не выводит изображение

Tags: captcha, php, zend-framework

не выводит html код на изображение.

Код формы:

```
$captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha', array(
        'label' => "Введите символы:",
        'captcha' => array(
            'captcha'   => 'Image', // Тип CAPTCHA
            'wordLen'   => 4,       // Количество генерируемых символов
            'width'     => 260,     // Ширина изображения
            'timeout'   => 120,     // Время жизни сессии хранящей символы
            'expiration'=> 30,     // Время жизни изображения в файловой системе
            'font'      => ROOT_PATH . '/images/fonts/comicbd.ttf', // Путь к шрифту
            'imgDir'    => ROOT_PATH . '/images/captcha/', // Путь к изобр.
            'imgUrl'    => '/images/captcha/', // Адрес папки с изображениями
            'gcFreq'    => 5        // Частота вызова сборщика мусора
        ),
    ));
```

HTML код вывода:

```
<tr><td id="captcha-input-label"><label for="captcha-input" class="required">Введите символы:</label></td>

<td>

<input type="hidden" name="captcha[id]" value="05ea6b5d7b6f60bd57a4e5e031496ead" id="captcha-id">

<input type="text" name="captcha[input]" id="captcha-input" value=""></td></tr>
```

Изображения создаются но ссылки на нее (**img**) не появляется. Подскажите в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
        'decorators' => array(
            array('Captcha'),
            array('Label'),
            array('Errors'),
            )
```